# Query Left Join with OR Inefficiency

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (200K rows) with a field called "Campaign". I have a separate table list of campaigns with additional information. I want to join on `where (campaign_id = campaign) OR (cid.spend_source = a.Traffic_Source AND a.Campaign = cid.Campaign_Name)`.

The problem I'm facing is that the OR statement is killing efficiency, causing a nested loop with 400 million rows.

What's a better method?

```
UPDATE a
SET    a.campaign_name = cid.Campaign_Name,
       a.Campaign_ID = cid.Campaign_ID
FROM   database.dbo.table a
       LEFT JOIN carb.dbo.carb_lookup_campaignid cid
              ON cid.Campaign_ID = a.Campaign
                  OR ( cid.spend_source = a.Traffic_Source
                       AND a.Campaign = cid.Campaign_Name )
```

Comment: use two separated update ..

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: This is non-standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: The LEFT JOIN is dangerous: it can cause NULL to be assigned to a.xxx (is that intended?) . Plus (depending on the data model) it can cause multiple values to be assigned to the same a.xxx tuple.

Answer (score 1):

Do two separate `left join`s:

```
UPDATE a
    SET a.campaign_name = coalesce(cidss.Campaign_Name, cidlc.Campaign_Name),
        a.Campaign_ID = coalesce(cidss.Campaign_ID, cidlc.Campaign_ID)
    FROM database.dbo.table a LEFT JOIN
         carb.dbo.carb_lookup_campaignid cidss
         ON cidss.Campaign_ID = a.Campaign and
            cidss.spend_source = a.Traffic_Source LEFT JOIN
         carb.dbo.carb_lookup_campaignid cidlc
         ON cidlc.Campaign_ID = a.Campaign and
            cidlc.Campaign_Name = a.Campaign and
            cidss.Campaign_ID is null
     WHERE cidss.Campaign_ID is not null or cidls.Campaign_ID is not null;
```

Each individual `LEFT JOIN` can take advantage of the appropriate index `(Campaign_ID, spend_source)` and `(Campaign_ID, Campaign_Name)`.

Answer (score 1):

Always use **MERGE** statement while updating from another table. You can use below query:

```
MERGE INTO a
USING 
(SELECT * FROM a
 LEFT OUTER JOIN carb_lookup_campaignid cid
ON (ON cid.Campaign_ID = a.Campaign)
OR ( cid.spend_source = a.Traffic_Source
                       AND a.Campaign = cid.Campaign_Name )
)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
UPDATE 
SET
a.campaign_name = cid.Campaign_Name,
a.Campaign_ID = cid.Campaign_ID
```

Comment: I like the syntax of `merge`, but the combination of not many people knowing it and it being susceptible to strange errors makes me avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Use two separated updated

```
  UPDATE a
  SET    a.campaign_name = cid.Campaign_Name,
         a.Campaign_ID = cid.Campaign_ID
  FROM   database.dbo.table a
  LEFT JOIN carb.dbo.carb_lookup_campaignid cid              
          ON cid.Campaign_ID = a.Campaign
  ;
```

and

```
  UPDATE a
  SET    a.campaign_name = cid.Campaign_Name,
         a.Campaign_ID = cid.Campaign_ID
  FROM   database.dbo.table a
  LEFT JOIN carb.dbo.carb_lookup_campaignid cid               
              ON ( cid.spend_source = a.Traffic_Source
                   AND a.Campaign = cid.Campaign_Name ) 
  ;
```